# Electromagnetic EM waves - How they coexist in same space and time without signal impact?

Tags: electromagnetism, wave

I'm having difficulty understanding how 2 EM waves from 2 sources can co exist in same space and time, without changing one another from a Quantum Electrodynamics Perspective.

If a charged source emits photons which excite electrons in Field Region X.... then how can another wave from a different source not impact the first EM wave due to an increase in Electron Excitation on ((same)) electrons in same Field Region X in same time.

I didn't think different electrons were excited by different wave sources... otherwise, how can Electron State = Wave1 .... when another Force from Wave2 is exerted on it?

Comment: "If you think you understand quantum mechanics, you don't understand quantum mechanics."- Richard Feynman

Comment: The funny thing in modern physics is that it's not supposed to be intuitive, clear or understandable. It is supposed to provide good models, and if you don't understand something- it's fine, just make sure you know the equation.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Good news it doesn't make sense to me! So I guess I "do" understand it! - In all seriousness though, is there not an answer or explanation to this?

Comment: It's what you get from equations. Don't look for anything more than that. All this stuff hints that our understanding of universe is very limited to Earth conditions (which is not a big surprise). Outside this range things behave differently, but our brains are not good enough to judge, this is why we need theories and math. Now from math you can see that a wave is in fact a change of properties of space/time that propagates from point to other point. It's a kind of a pure information going through space. As such, maybe it's fine not to interfere with other wave.

Comment: How do two waves on water occupy the same space and time?

Comment: @laptop2d That's a question roaming in my mind... is there an explanation? Or it's just "what happens"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The electrons will be excited by a superposition (sum) of the two EM waves. The waves will pass through each other much like waves on a pond. There is no differentiation between waves from different sources.

Occasionally it is possible to run in to nonlinearities that depend on the overall amplitude of the EM waves in question, and in this case all of the waves would be affected.

Comment: Thank you Alex. But wouldn't this superposition sum impact the signal read from the antenna? Wouldn't the superposition on 1 Electron have higher energy and therefore emit its energy to the next Electron in the wave and so on. So the amplitude would be different from original signal. Is amplitude fluctuations in this case not cared for by signal reading and processing?

Comment: The antenna will certainly see the superposition of all EM waves in its environment. This is why you need to use a filter to select the frequency you want to receive - the antenna will receive everything. If there are two signals at the same frequency, then a tuner cannot distinguish between the two. However, it is possible to make antennas directional so that they will receive waves preferentially from a particular direction.

Comment: Would the superposition from another wave not excite the 'same' Electron in the original wave and therefore change its amplitude parameters from energy transfer process to all other electrons? So the wave itself becomes different because of 1 instance of superposition? Or am I not getting this right?

Comment: The electrons don't see discrete waves, they see the EM field. Which would be the superposition, or sum, of the incoming waves.

Answer (score 1):

You assume some electrons and also two waves in region X and wondered: "no interaction"?

The interaction can result to something that quite soon collapses returning the original waves that go on, only some extra time have been spent in X

Other possiblity is an irreversible interaction. Try to put a cellphone near some audio system,take a call and listen. You very likely can hear the consequences of the irreversible interaction.

Comment: But does a circuit have E&M waves in the PCB traces?

Comment: Nothing but waves carry energy in circuits. It's the fields between the metal parts. The current is an induced consequence. Only 0Hz without changes for ever do not have a wave.

Comment: Fortunately the voltage and the current are a good approximative way to follow the total effects of the waves in a small area

Answer (score 1):

The carrier of an [EM wave is a photon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_carrier), photons don't (most of the time) interact with each other. Photons interact with electrons and other 'stuff' but can pass right through each other. If you delve into this question further its like asking why do triangles angles add up to 180 (in a normal geometric sense). Or why did the universe come to be. The answer is, they just are.

If you study the [math behind it](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wavsol.html) you can find out what constitutes a wave and how waves pass right through each other unimpeded.

Comment: So it is a finite number of photons which get created from source and travel through electrons exciting them to create the wave. So the photons created at source travel out until wave dissipates with distance.. my understanding was that electrons absorb source's photons then each Electron emits photons to neighbor Electron giving it its "superposition" energy... but if it's only the source's photons... then it would answer why 2 waves can coexist. Is that your understanding as well?

Comment: Waves only dissipate if the magnetic or electric field is attenuated, this can happen if the fields are not matched. In the case of light emitted from an atom the electric field and magnetic field amplitude are matched and the photon never attenuates and goes on forever. There are electromagnetic waves that do attenuate.